# taking and uploading a image to website in android studio photo not found

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, post

I'm very new to java and android studio i have about 5 days under my belt from just going at it but I've ran into a snag i need help figuring out how to have android studio recognize the file path of a photo.

This program should open and display a imageView on the mainActivity and when you click it it will open up the camera and allow you to take a photo after you take the photo it backs out into the mainActivity and displays the full resolution photo in the imageView and uploads the photo to a website running some php code listening for posts and writing them to the online storage folder
everything works fine except when it tries to upload the photo it will say no file exists ive checked the storage on the device the photo is there maybe its because i had to use a FileProvider to make the uri go from file to content in order to save the image the php scrip works so im in need of help solving the cant find the file issue thank you for your help in advanced
the project code is below
device:Galexy note 8

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.photo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/file_provider_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.photo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public interface ApplicationConstant {
        String UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL = "http://www.example.com/upload.php";
        String TAG = "DEBUG1";
    }
    String Barcode="9999";

    int permsRequestCode;
    int RC_PERMISSIONS;

    final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri photoUri;
    ImageView mImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        mImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG," " + "click");
                showCamera();
            }
        });
    }

    private class uploadFileToServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Object> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                @SuppressWarnings("PointlessArithmeticExpression")
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;


                java.net.URL url = new URL((ApplicationConstant.UPLOAD_IMAGE_URL));
                Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG, "url " + url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Set HTTP method to POST.
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                FileInputStream fileInputStream;
                DataOutputStream outputStream;
                {
                    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    String filename =  args[0];
                    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + filename + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG, "filename: " + filename);

                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // Read file
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                }

                int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
                Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG, "serverResponseCode: " + serverResponseCode);
                Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG, "serverResponseMessage: " + serverResponseMessage);

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    return "true";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "false";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (photoUri != null) {
                    mImg.setImageURI(photoUri);
                    Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG,"photo_Uri: " + photoUri);
                    new uploadFileToServerTask().execute(photoUri.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File file = null;
            try {
                file = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            photoUri = null;
            if (file != null) {
                photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                        getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
                        file);
                //photoUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
           File storageDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),Barcode + ".jpg");
        // File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return storageDir;
    }
}
```

values/strings.xml

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Photo</string>
        <string name="file_provider_authority" translatable="false">com.example.photo.fileprovider</string>
    </resources>
```

xml/file_provider_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "";  
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Logcat

```
03-20 02:33:39.234 32312-32312/? E/Zygote: v2
03-20 02:33:39.235 32312-32312/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10276
03-20 02:33:39.235 32312-32312/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-20 02:33:39.235 32312-32312/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
03-20 02:33:39.236 32312-32312/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.1.1_0004, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
03-20 02:33:39.236 32312-32312/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.photo 
03-20 02:33:39.241 32312-32312/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-20 02:33:39.452 32312-32312/com.example.photo I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
03-20 02:33:39.510 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/ActivityThread: performLaunchActivity: mActivityCurrentConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc260mnc [en_US,ja_JP] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h773dp 560dpi nrml long port ?dc finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h mkbd/h desktop/d s.112}
03-20 02:33:39.522 32312-32312/com.example.photo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-20 02:33:39.611 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
03-20 02:33:39.612 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
03-20 02:33:39.649 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
03-20 02:33:39.653 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=87
03-20 02:33:39.654 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@94b80fc[MainActivity] touchMode=true
03-20 02:33:39.663 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
03-20 02:33:39.688 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
03-20 02:33:39.688 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 548279813120} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
03-20 02:33:39.688 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 548279813120} hwInitialized=true
03-20 02:33:39.691 32312-32379/com.example.photo D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
03-20 02:33:39.703 32312-32379/com.example.photo D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
03-20 02:33:39.709 32312-32312/com.example.photo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
03-20 02:33:39.711 32312-32379/com.example.photo D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
03-20 02:33:39.715 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=1
03-20 02:33:39.715 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
03-20 02:33:39.715 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 548279813120}
03-20 02:33:39.716 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@72b6a0b nm : com.example.photo ic=null
03-20 02:33:39.716 32312-32312/com.example.photo I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
03-20 02:33:39.721 32312-32324/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=95
03-20 02:33:39.725 32312-32379/com.example.photo I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 33f9106, Ia8660bee96
                                                           Build Date                       : 08/09/17
                                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.14.00.01
                                                           Local Branch                     : 
                                                           Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.7.C2.07.01.01.292.070
                                                           Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                           Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
03-20 02:33:39.726 32312-32379/com.example.photo I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff104, ME: 0x005ff063
03-20 02:33:39.727 32312-32379/com.example.photo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-20 02:33:39.727 32312-32379/com.example.photo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-20 02:33:39.745 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@b83b500 nm : com.example.photo ic=null
03-20 02:33:42.813 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-20 02:33:42.888 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-20 02:33:42.891 32312-32312/com.example.photo I/DEBUG1:  click
03-20 02:33:42.915 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
03-20 02:33:43.165 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
03-20 02:33:43.173 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
03-20 02:33:43.173 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=95
03-20 02:33:49.502 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
03-20 02:33:49.508 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
03-20 02:33:49.531 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
03-20 02:33:49.532 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] newFrame=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x7 surface={isValid=true 548279813120} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
03-20 02:33:49.532 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 548279813120} hwInitialized=true
03-20 02:33:49.545 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
03-20 02:33:49.545 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 548279813120}
03-20 02:33:49.545 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4c32418 nm : com.example.photo ic=null
03-20 02:33:49.545 32312-32312/com.example.photo I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
03-20 02:33:49.547 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=91
03-20 02:33:49.797 32312-32312/com.example.photo I/DEBUG1: photo_Uri: content://com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg
03-20 02:33:49.799 32312-2026/com.example.photo I/DEBUG1: url http://www.example.com/upload.php
03-20 02:33:49.802 32312-2026/com.example.photo D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
03-20 02:33:49.803 32312-2026/com.example.photo I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-20 02:33:49.803 32312-2026/com.example.photo I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-20 02:33:49.903 32312-2026/com.example.photo D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo I/DEBUG1: filename: content://com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg (No such file or directory)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:99)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at com.example.photo.MainActivity$uploadFileToServerTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:94)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at com.example.photo.MainActivity$uploadFileToServerTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
03-20 02:33:52.113 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
03-20 02:33:52.113 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@4c4ddef[MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
03-20 02:33:52.117 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=87
03-20 02:33:52.117 32312-32312/com.example.photo W/SemDesktopModeManager: unregisterListener: Listener is null
03-20 02:33:52.120 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/ActivityThread: performLaunchActivity: mActivityCurrentConfig={0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 310mcc260mnc [en_US,ja_JP] ldltr sw411dp w797dp h387dp 560dpi nrml long land ?dc finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h mkbd/h desktop/d s.113}
03-20 02:33:52.134 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
03-20 02:33:52.134 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
03-20 02:33:52.141 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
03-20 02:33:52.179 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=93
03-20 02:33:52.179 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@8545f1d[MainActivity] touchMode=true
03-20 02:33:52.183 32312-32312/com.example.photo E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
03-20 02:33:52.183 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
03-20 02:33:52.210 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
03-20 02:33:52.211 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][2960,1440] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 548279813120} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
03-20 02:33:52.211 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 548279813120} hwInitialized=true
03-20 02:33:52.220 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 2960, 1440) ci=Rect(168, 84 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(168, 84 - 0, 0) or=2
03-20 02:33:52.231 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
03-20 02:33:52.231 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/ViewRootImpl@b05cbf4[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 548279813120}
03-20 02:33:52.232 32312-32312/com.example.photo V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@e558592 nm : com.example.photo ic=null
03-20 02:33:52.232 32312-32312/com.example.photo I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
03-20 02:33:52.236 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=95
03-20 02:33:52.236 32312-32312/com.example.photo D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=91
```

Comment: `when it tries to upload the photo it will say no file exists` Who is saying so? And where? Exception? WHy are you posting that irrelevant log? And dumped all that code?

Comment: `outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);` that should be `outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);`

Comment: `new uploadFileToServerTask().execute(photoUri.toString());` What is the value of `photoUri.toString()` ?

Comment: in the log posted it says '03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo I/DEBUG1: filename: content://com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg
03-20 02:33:49.983 32312-2026/com.example.photo W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg (No such file or directory)
' when the camera intent is called  it creates a temp jpeg file the path should be stored in photoUri, the photoUri will work for setting the image view photo

Comment: Well that is not a file! Things that start with content:// are no files. So you cannot use FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String filename ="content://com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg";

FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(filename);
```

You cannot use a file input stream as you have no file scheme. You have a content scheme. So change to:

```
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(filename));
```

And use that stream as you did before.

Instead of this content scheme of your own file provider you could have directly use a file path. As it is you who determined the path or the picture to be taken. You dumped a lot of irrelevant code here and omitted the setup of the used intent.

Comment: i got it to work thank you for some reason i noticed that when i send the filename that contains "content://com.example.photo.fileprovider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.photo/files/Pictures/9999.jpg" to the uploadFileToServerTask class  and read its value with args[0] it looses the pretex content://com.example.photo.fileprovider i ended up manually adding it

Answer (score 0):

In your `onActivityResult` you are trying to get the URI for the file you provided for capturing. So it says that no file found.
Instead try to get the url from Intent received inside the method

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    photoUri= data.getData();
                    mImg.setImageURI(photoUri);
                    Log.i(ApplicationConstant.TAG,"photo_Uri: " + photoUri);
                    new uploadFileToServerTask().execute(photoUri.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tied this but got a new exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.photo/com.example.photo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)`